# set images url to background attribute using concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What's wrong with my concatenation below?

```
$(function(){

    var bg = "http://i.imgur.com/kqRNO6M.jpg";
    var html = '<div style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)),url(\"'+ bg +'\") no-repeat;">';
});
```

my demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/su3fpkex/

I escaped double quote with `\` but couldn't seem working.

Comment: `console.log(html)` and check the quotes ;)

Comment: I'm confused...you set some variables then don't do anything with them?

Answer (score 2):

try with this:

```
$(function(){

  var bg = "http://i.imgur.com/kqRNO6M.jpg";
  var html = '<div style=\'background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)),url("'+ bg +'") no-repeat;\'>';

});
```

and remember to append somewhere your `html` variable! :)

Comment: sure, you have to use your "html" variable in one way or another :D it's just to explain how to concatenate correctly these strings :)

Comment: this work but i don't understant the concatenation here, why escpae from the beginning?

Comment: if you escape the ' when specifying attributes you can use plain quotes inside the string. I prefer this way :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the html content in the page:

```
$(function(){

    var bg = "http://i.imgur.com/kqRNO6M.jpg";
    var html = '<div style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)),url(\''+ bg +'\') no-repeat;">';
    $('body').append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){

    var bg = "http://i.imgur.com/kqRNO6M.jpg";
    var html = '<div style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)),url(\''+ bg +'\') no-repeat;">';

    alert(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set background image you have to set width and height for div.

```
<div class='img'></div>

$(function(){
   var bg = "http://i.imgur.com/kqRNO6M.jpg";
   var html = '<div style="width:300px;height:300px;background-size:cover;background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)),url(\''+ bg +'\') no-repeat;">';
    $('.img').html(html);

});
```